# Can an Apple iPod Classic 160 GB work with with iTunes or macOS in 2022?

Tags: macos, ipod-classic

I have one that I use in an older car that I want to reformat using iTunes or Finder in macOS.

What is the last version of iTunes that supported the iPod Classic 160 GB?

Answer (score 12):

The current version of iTunes [supports the iPod classic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/412477/5472) (2009, 160GB). In fact, it supports all iPods, all iPhones, and all iPads.

The source is myself, I just synced my 2009 iPod with iTunes earlier today.

Comment: By 'current version' do you mean the last available for Mac, 12.9.5.5, the current version for Windows, 12.12.4, or do you actually mean Apple Music?

Comment: @Tetsujin I mean both, as well as Finder/Music on non-iTunes versions of macOS. I checked Mactracker, seems like you need iTunes 9 or later, running on Windows Vista or Mac OS X 10.4.11 or newer.

Answer (score 4):

Currently (May 2022) the iPod Classic is supported by the latest version of iTunes (v12) on Windows and macOS, as well as the subsequent sync with the "Music" app via Finder in macOS Catalina - Monterey.