# Apple mobile device support needed to sync iPod Classic

Tags: data-synchronization, ipod

I've been trying to update/sync my vintage iPod Classic.  I've come to understand what is required to connect this older iPod to iTunes is "Apple mobile device support".  I tried to install this driver separately, but as soon as I do, iTunes tells me I am not using a current version of iTunes and won't let me open iTunes without updating to the latest version that excludes/removes the requisite "Apple mobile device support".  I'm guessing iTunes intentionally stopped supporting old iPods?  Any possible workaround would be appreciated.  I am using iTunes on Windows 10.  My newer iPod touch still syncs without issue.

Comment: See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441352/can-an-apple-ipod-classic-160-gb-work-with-with-itunes-or-macos-in-2022 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412456/what-version-of-itunes-dropped-synchronization-support-for-ipod-classic

Comment: Wait...this doesn't make sense.  You have iTunes but it doesn't have the "mobile device support driver."  To install the driver, you need to upgrade iTunes that doesn't have/will remove the aforementioned support.  How can you break something that wasn't installed in the first place?